# Filtering and exporting data based on condition

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I have a responses sheet (synced to a Google Form) which has many columns (over 100).
The responses can either be Yes/No and if the response is No - there is a free text response required.
I want to separate the No's and the Free-text responses from the rest - ideally in a different sheet.
This filtering should be somewhat automated so that each time I get a new response, I do not need to amend the formula, etc.
I have tried filtering the data by colour and exporting it via SheetGo - but it only allows me to select one column as a reference and I have more than one.
I have tried using a Query/filter function with an IF clause - but I still get a few Yes coming across.
Would anyone be able to assist, please? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: have you tried https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9759608?hl=en and use the data at your computer with better tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a new sheet, use the formula:

`=filter(FormData!A2:B, FormData!A2:A="No")`

Change `FormData` to the name of your sheet where form responses are entered. Change `A2:B` with the range of your data that you want filtered out (If the yes/no responses are not in adjacent columns, you can change the filter range to something like `{FormData!A2:A, FormData!G2:G}`). And finally, change `A2:A` with the range of the "Yes/No" responses.

Example of all this shown below:

> **Form Data:**
> [image]
> **Filter:**
> [image]

> **Form Data:**
> [image]
> **Filter:**
> [image]

Please let me know if you have any questions. Hope this helps!

---

### Edit

Here is an updated answer based on clarifications made in the comments.

> Raw Response Sheet:
> [image: resp]

> Filtered Sheet:
> [image: filtered]
>
> > Cell `A1`:
> > `={"User",arrayformula(filter(if((a!$A$2:$L$2="Yes"), offset(a!$A$1:$L$1,0,1), if(a!$A$2:$L$2="No", offset(a!$A$1:$L$1,0,1), "")),if((a!$A$2:$L$2="Yes"),a!$A$1:$L$1, if(a!$A$2:$L$2="No", a!$A$1:$L$1, ""))<>""))}`
>
> This formula finds the headers for yes/no questions based on the first set of responses. If a question is answered Yes or No, the header is set. The first header is set to be "User". Please change this to whatever the identifying header is named in your sheet.
>
> > Cell `A2`:
> > `=QUERY(a!$A$2:$L$9,"SELECT "&join(",",arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($A$1:$D$1,a!$A$1:$L$1,0),4),1,""))))`
>
> This formula matches the header names with the headers from the raw response sheet, finds the columns, and uses these references to query the results.
>
> For **both** of these formulas:
>
> - Replace all `a!$A$2:$L$2` and `a!$A$1:$L$1` with the columns that hold your data. There is no need to change the row numbers.
> - Replace `$A$1:$D$1` (in the second formula) with the top row of your filtered sheet. This references the headers of the Yes/No questions and user identifiers.
>   Replace all `a!` references with the name of your raw response sheet (ie `[nameOfSheet]!`).

I broke these formulas apart to help keep things neater and more understandable. Here is a single formula solution that can be placed in cell `A1` of the filtered sheet:

```
={"User",arrayformula(filter(if((a!$A$2:$L$2="Yes"), offset(a!$A$1:$L$1,0,1), if(a!$A$2:$L$2="No", offset(a!$A$1:$L$1,0,1), "")),if((a!$A$2:$L$2="Yes"),a!$A$1:$L$1, if(a!$A$2:$L$2="No", a!$A$1:$L$1, ""))<>""));QUERY(a!$A$2:$L$9,"SELECT "&join(",",arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH({"User",arrayformula(filter(if((a!$A$2:$L$2="Yes"), offset(a!$A$1:$L$1,0,1), if(a!$A$2:$L$2="No", offset(a!$A$1:$L$1,0,1), "")),if((a!$A$2:$L$2="Yes"),a!$A$1:$L$1, if(a!$A$2:$L$2="No", a!$A$1:$L$1, ""))<>""))},a!$A$1:$L$1,0),4),1,""))))}
```

This formula would need to also be edited as listed out above, which can be trickier given how jumbled this formula appears. A simple find and replace can work wonders here.

Comment: Thank you @kaitlynmm569 - this is helpful! I forgot to specify in my original message/question that I have over 100 columns that correspond to the questions from my Google form - meaning that I have Yes and No as a response to many of those columns. I was trying to tackle all of those No's with a formula without having to reference each column one by one - if that's even possible? Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Ohh okay, I understand better now. Is "yes/no" a possible answer to any other question in the form? Also, is the free response answer always directly after the yes/no response? I will edit my answer once I am able to find a full solution for you :)

Comment: Thank you @kaitlynmm569 ! The google form was built following this logic: Question1 - answer Yes or No; if Yes, moves to question 2; if No, a pop-up question appears requiring a free-text answer and then moves on to question 2. On the spreadsheet, it looks like Col B = Question 1 (with answers yes/no) - Col C = Pop-up question (free text answers when No was selected in previous question) - Col D = Question 2 (with answers yes/no) and so on... Thank you very much for your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: @Martha No problem! Just one last quick thing. Would you be able to edit your question with an example of what you expect the result to look like? Given that this is an array of data, and different users are going to answer yes/no to various different questions, I'm just trying to get an idea of how this would be best formatted. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @kaitlynmm569 - apologies if I did not understand your question fully. The questions on the Google form where I expect Yes or No for an answer, follow the multiple-choice format - so the user would only be able to select from those 2 options (Yes/No). I would be able to edit the question as well if that is needed :)

Comment: @Martha Thank you, I understand that part. What I'm asking is more of what do you expect the sheet to look like once it has filtered all of the responses? For example, do you want to be able to tell which question was answered yes/no, or rather just the responses themselves? Just simply how the resulting sheet should *look*. I just ask because that could change the formulas/methods used to complete this task.

Comment: Ohh sorry - yes this is a good point. Ideally, I would like the resulting sheet to have a header row with the questions so I can tell which questions were answered No and what were the free text answers associated with those No's. Thank you @kaitlynmm569 !!

Comment: @Martha my answer has been updated with some new formulas. I hope this helps!